# Has anyone successfully exported xidel output vars to cmd?

Tags: xml, windows, cmd

I'm using xidel to extract a value from a specific tag in a XML file, and export it as a var to cmd. However, the vars don't seem to be exported at all.

example I'm using:

xidel "in.xml" -e "{var1:=text()}" --output-format cmd

I get the output:

```
**** Retrieving:in.xml ****  
**** Processing: in.xml ****  
** Current variable state: **  
SET var1=1234
```

(where 1234 is contained in in.xml)
but var1 is not set as a variable available from the command prompt window.
This is on a Windows 7 machine. Any insight would be much appreciated - I don't know if I'm using xidel incorrectly or there's a bug with cmd var output.

Answer (score 1):

No, you're not using Xidel correctly.
First of all, the only way to make Xidel variables available in cmd is through the use of a FOR-loop.
Secondly, in this situation you shouldn't enclose your query with curly brackets. Those are meant for creating JSONs, amongst other things.
And thirdly, officially it's `--output-format=cmd`, but I guess Benito - Xidel's author - has been forgiving for people who forget the `=`, as `--output-format cmd` seems to work as well. Should you use the `=`, don't forget to escape it with a `^`, because [it's a special character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/2703456).

So your FOR-loop would then look like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('xidel.exe -s "in.xml" -e "var1:=..." --output-format^=cmd') DO %%A
```

Answer (score 0):

See how this works

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xidel "in.xml" -e "{var1:=text()}" --output-format cmd ^|find /i "set " ') do %%a
set var1
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

For one or more variables:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('xidel "in.xml" -s --output-format=cmd -e "{var1:=...}" -e "{var2:=...}" -e "{var3:=...}"') do %%a

echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%

pause
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, so new/others can understand it more easily.