# How to extract data from file with xidel with custom delimiter?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line-interface, data-extraction, xidel

```
variable=data
```

How do I extract `data`? I need to set `variable=` somehow. Running `xidel file.txt -e "variable="` gives error `err:XPST0003: Unexpected query end` and removing `=` gives no results.

Comment: `for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %L in ("variable=data") do set "VALUE=%L"`, then `echo %VALUE%` to display data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually xidel is meant to extract data from structured data like xml/html/json with languages like xquery/xpath/templates/jsonic... and is not particularly designed for text based extraction. However, you can toy with $raw and regular expression functions like extract() and replace() to try and get the variable.

So for example, if you have a file.txt with contents like:

```
var1=one
var2=two
var3=three
```

you can do the following:

```
xidel -s file.txt -e "output:=extract($raw,'var2=(.*)',1)"
```

And the result is:

```
output := two
```

Now, assuming you're on windows, you can export this to an environment variable with a for loop and --output-format cmd, like the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38599599/3910330